# How do i get random value in c++ 11

Tags: c++, c++11

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

void main()
{
  std::random_device rd;

  std::cout << "Random value: " << rd() << std::endl;

  system("pause");
}
```

How do i get the result `rd()`, and convert it to `std::string`?

Comment: `main` has to return `int`.

Comment: Google seems to help plenty -- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device

Comment: main automatically returns an int in c++, Shafik. There's no specific need to, although it might be good style to.

Comment: @Nathan he has `void main` which is not valid.

Comment: Ah, I didn't see that, you're right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are asking how to convert the result of `std::random_device` to a string, and `std::random_device` returns an `unsigned int`.  **C++11** provides `std::to_string`, can be used to convert numbers to strings. See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <string>

int main()
{

    std::random_device rd;
    std::string str = std::to_string(rd());
    std::cout << str << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm getting "error: 'tostring' is not a member of 'std'" with -std=gnu++11

Comment: it is `std::to_string`

Comment: @Kevin typo of `std::to_string` already correct it.

Comment: The problem remains....

Comment: @Kevin I used a online gcc C++11 compiler and it works fine, http://www.compileonline.com/compile_cpp11_online.php

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example I found on http://en.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enwiki/11574016

```
#include <random>
#include <functional>

std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(0, 99);
std::mt19937 engine; // Mersenne twister MT19937
auto generator = std::bind(distribution, engine);
int random = generator();  // Generate a uniform integral variate between 0 and 99.
int random2 = distribution(engine); // Generate another sample directly using the       distribution and the engine objects.
```

I haven't worked with it before, but this might help you get started.

Answer (score 1):

[`std::stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) is one way to convert a number to a string, the code below shows various engines and distributions possible. It defaults to `Mersenne Twister` for the engine and the `normal distribution`. This is good [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) for the options available:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <random>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;

    //
    // Engines 
    //
    std::mt19937 e2(rd());
    //std::knuth_b e2(rd());
    //std::default_random_engine e2(rd()) ;

    //
    // Distribtuions
    //
    std::normal_distribution<> dist(2, 2);
    //std::student_t_distribution<> dist(5);
    //std::poisson_distribution<> dist(2);
    //std::extreme_value_distribution<> dist(0,2);

    std::stringstream s1 ;

    s1 << dist(e2) ; 

    std::string str1 = s1.str();

    std::cout << str1 << std::endl ;
}
```

another method to convert to a `string` would be to use [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string):

```
 str1 = std::to_string( dist(e2) ) ;
```

Comment: Thanks,I have been solved the question :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(){
    srand(time(NULL));
    unsigned int maxValue = 50;
    std::cout << "Random value: " << rand()%maxValue; //random between 0-50

    return 0;
}
```